# Trying to interrupt a thread stuck in reader.readLine()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, streamreader, irc

I have a connection with an IRC server over TCP. I read the data with an independent task, so far, so good. However, if I want to quit the program, I can't quit the thread because it is stuck in the reader.ReadLine() command (threadShouldRun has no impact). Using Interrupt() or Abort() doesn't appear to change anything either.

Either I need a way to determine when there are more lines to read, or I need to forcefully kill the thread (even though that's bad).

```
private System.Threading.Thread myThread;
private bool threadShouldRun = true;
private StreamReader reader;

private void readStream()
{
    while(threadShouldRun)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line != null)
        {
            newLineEvent(this, new NewLineEventArgs(line));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong - if you got TCP communication which you need to react to - you should use sockets. I don't think you will be able to gracefully end a waiting `ReadLine`.

Comment: Pretty unclear what the *reader* is reading from.  But if it is a network stream then you can simply get it to stop by closing the socket.  Be prepared to catch the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asynchronous calls like BeginRead as shown here and avoid the loop:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to set a `TimeOut` on your receiving socket ( [http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ).

Once the time expires, a `SocketException` will be raised, so you can catch it and reiterate the control on your threadShouldRun.

In case you want to quit (and hence set threadShouldRun to false), there are two scenarios:

1. Data received, you will handle it, and on the next check the variable will be found false and thread will terminate;
2. No Data received, `TimeOut` happens, Exception is raised, you will handle it, and on the check the thread will terminate.